# Recursively search .mp4 files and process them with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, bash-scripting

I have a bunch of .mp4 video files which are located in different folders. I would like to process all of these video files with ffmpeg using the following command on Ubuntu (the processed video is stored with a new filename):

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -vf scale=w=320:h=-1 -y -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -r 20 output_video
```

I would like to do this with a bash script which recursively searches all .mp4 video files which contains the string "xyz" in the filename and as root folder I would like to use `/media/myShare`.

In addition, from time to time I add new video files to subdirectories. When I rerun the script I don't want to process the already converted ones and only process the newly added ones. How can all this be done?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your OS? The "batch" tag slightly suggests Windows. This "in addition…" part is a separate issue (could be a separate question) and makes the entire question prone to being closed as "too broad". Please [edit] the question and improve it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski My OS is Ubuntu. I have remvode the batch tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few properties your script-to-be must have, let's just walk through them one by one:

**Recursivly find all MP4 files with a pattern in their filename and process them**

Here your friend is `find` - you don't need most of the options, so something along the lines of `find "$STARTFOLDER" -type f -name '*$PATTERN*.mp4'` is a good start. You can iterate over these with a `for` construct

**What you didn't mention: Auto-create a new filename**

You might want to try to use `basename` for that, something along the lines of `BN=$(basename "$FILEPATH" '.mp4'); BP=$(dirname "$FILEPATH"); NEWFILENAME="$BP/$BN-converted.mp4"` looks good.

**Putting it all together**

Now that we have all building bricks, we just need to wire things up:

```
#!/bin/bash

STARTFOLDER="/media/myShare"
PATTERN="xyz"
MARKER="converted"

echo -n "Finding candidate files .."
FILELIST=$(find "$STARTFOLDER" -type f -name '*$PATTERN*.mp4')
echo ".. "$(echo -e "$FILELIST" | wc -l)" found"

while read FILEPATH; do
  # A bit of healthy paranoia
  test -z "$FILEPATH" && continue
  test -f "$FILEPATH" || continue
  echo -n "Working on $FILEPATH .."

  # New file name
  BN=$(basename "$FILEPATH" '.mp4')
  BP=$(dirname "$FILEPATH")
  NEWFILEPATH="$BP/$BN-$MARKER.mp4"

  # Skip result files
  ISRESULT=$(echo "$BN" | grep -e "$MARKER\\.mp4\$")
  if test -n "$ISRESULT"; then
    echo "..  skipping (is a result file)"
    continue
  fi

  # Skip processed files
  if test -f "$NEWFILEPATH"; then
    echo "..  skipping (result file exists)"
    continue
  fi

  # Process
  echo -n ".. running ffmpeg .."
  RES=$(ffmpeg -i "$FILEPATH" -vf scale=w=320:h=-1 -y -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -r 20 "$NEWFILEPATH" </dev/null 2>&1)
  echo ".. done (exit code $?)"

done < <(echo -e "$FILELIST")
```

**Caveat:** This is completly untested, typos are likely

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After converting I have the original file and the converted file with the MARKER in the filename. So long so good, but when I rerun the script it only excludes the files with the MARKER in the filename but not the original files. I would like to exclude the original file as well as the newly created MARKER files and only include files which have not yet been processed (i.e. which I have added after running the script).

Comment: I edited the script to skip the result files as well and produce better readable output.

Comment: When I uncomment the line with the ffmpeg command it loops through all the files perfectly. But when the ffmpeg  command is activated the first file is processed correctly and ".. done (exit code 0)" is printed but afterwards the next file is no more processed and the scripts ends (i.e. the while loops is exited). Do you know why?

Comment: My bad - `ffmpeg` consumes stdin, which ruins the loop. I have edited the answer to provide stdin redirection for ffmpeg

Comment: Why do yow capture `RES` into a variable you never use? Overall, this is mired by variable captures which are mostly unnecessary and sometimes inefficient. Also, use lower case for your private variables.

Comment: @tripleee Capturing `RES`e.g.  is a prelude for extending the script to show the output of ffmpeg, if it fails. You are however welcome to provide a better answer, including lower-case variables.

Comment: No way to do that on a closed question, I'm afraid.